# Detecting a timeout exception on a Java Future without calling get() on it

Tags: java, concurrency, timeout, future, callable

I am building a library that needs to some bluetooth operations on Android. I want to return a Future instance, so whoever is using my library can call .get() on the future returned and can handle ExecutionException, TimeoutException and InterruptedException themselves. However, I want to detect a timeout myself because I need to some cleanup logic like disconnecting from the device and so on. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which timeout do you want to detect? The `TimeoutException` is thrown when the timeout *provided by the caller of the `get` method* has been elapsed. That doesn’t affect the actual ongoing operation. There can be an arbitrary number of callers for a single future, each using a different timeout. The same caller could call `get` again after a timeout. Neither of these actions implies that it’s time for a cleanup.

Comment: @Holger I am allowed to assume that there is only one caller of my library/API as this is a project for a dedicated client, we can make demands on that.

I want to detect the timeout, then interrupt whatever is going on and then do cleanup. I suspect this requirement is compatible with returning a Future

Comment: So you are returning a `Future` to suggest that the caller has the freedom to use that API and then, you add constraints contradicting the purpose of that API? Doesn’t sound like a good idea. Besides that, it doesn’t even solve the problem. When a caller provided timeout has been elapsed, the actual operation still is ongoing. So it’s not the right point to do a cleanup.

Comment: No, that’s not compatible with the `Future` API. A timeout is not a cancellation. A timeout means that a caller specified maximum waiting time is over. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a wrapper class around `Future` which delegates to a different one (the one returned by wherever you're getting your `Future` at the moment).  Something like:

```
final class DelegatingFuture<T> implements Future<T> {

    private final Future<T> delegate;

    DelegatingFuture(final Future<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = Objects.requireNonNull(delegate);
    }

    // All other methods simply delegate to 'delegate'
    @Override
    public T get() 
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        try {
            return this.delegate.get();
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            // Handle cleanup...
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    // Something similar for get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
}
```

And then simply `return new DelegatingFuture<>(currentFuture);` wherever your handing these out.

Comment: That would be one possibility but I would be happier not to return a custom class as an API return value to the client that used the library.

Comment: That's why it `implements Future<T>`.  You simply return `Future<T>` from your API, the actual _implementation_ of that interface isn't made visible (hence it being a non-`public` class).

Comment: Yes, I realized that now. Thank you, that would certainly be one possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is relevant to the caller of the `get` method with timeout and *only* to that caller. A timeout is nowhere meant to imply a cancellation. E.g., the following code is a legitimate usage of the `Future` API:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Future<String> f = es.submit(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    return "hello";
});

for(;;) try {
    String s = f.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println("got "+s);
    break;
}
catch(TimeoutException ex) {
    // perhaps, do some other work
    System.out.println("will wait something more");
}
catch (ExecutionException ex) {
    System.out.println("failed with "+ex);
    break;
}

es.shutdown();
```

Tying the cleanup to the methods actually intended to query the result, is not a useful approach. The timeout provided by the caller(s) of that method do not relate to the actual operation. There’s not even a guaranty that the result will be queried before the operations ends or that it gets queried at all.

The cleanup should happen when either, the operation finished or when the future gets cancelled explicitly. If the caller intends a cancellation after a timeout, the caller only needs to invoke `cancel` after catching a `TimeoutException`.
One approach, often pointed to, is to use a `CompletionService`, e.g.

```
static final ExecutorService MY__EXECUTOR = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
static final CompletionService<String> COMPLETION_SERVICE
    = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(MY__EXECUTOR);
static final Future<?> CLEANER = MY__EXECUTOR.submit(() -> {
        for(;;) try {
            Future<String> completed = COMPLETION_SERVICE.take();
            System.out.println("cleanup "+completed);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            if(MY__EXECUTOR.isShutdown()) break;
        }
    });

public static Future<String> doSomeWork() {
    return COMPLETION_SERVICE.submit(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return "hello";
    });
}
```

You are in control over when to poll the completed futures, like in another background thread, as shown in the example, or right before commencing new jobs.

You can test it like

```
Future<String> f = doSomeWork();
try {
    String s = f.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println("got "+s);
}
catch(TimeoutException ex) {
    System.out.println("no result after 500ms");
}
catch (ExecutionException ex) {
    System.out.println("failed with "+ex);
}

if(f.cancel(true)) System.out.println("canceled");

f = doSomeWork();
// never calling get() at all
```

But honestly, I never understood why such complicated things are actually necessary. If you want a cleanup at the right time, you can use

```
static final ExecutorService MY__EXECUTOR = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public static Future<String> doSomeWork() {
    Callable<String> actualJob = () -> {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return "hello";
    };
    FutureTask<String> ft = new FutureTask<>(actualJob) {
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            System.out.println("cleanup "+this);
        }
    };
    MY__EXECUTOR.execute(ft);
    return ft;
}
```

to achieve the same.

Or even simpler

```
static final ExecutorService MY__EXECUTOR = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public static Future<String> doSomeWork() {
    Callable<String> actualJob = () -> {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        return "hello";
    };
    return MY__EXECUTOR.submit(() -> {
        try {
            return actualJob.call();
        }
        finally {
            // perform cleanup
            System.out.println("cleanup");
        }
    });
}
```

In either case, the cleanup will be performed whether the job was completed successfully, failed, or got canceled. If `cancel(true)` was used and the actual job supports interruption, the cleanup also will be performed immediately after.

Comment: Well, I understand the theoretical background. The operations I do with Bluetooth are stateful though and I know that the client will retry the entire operation when they walk into a timeout. So i have to make sure I rollback certain things and disconnect from the remote device when they walk into a timeout. I guess your last simple example works perfectly fine for my usecase.

Comment: This sounds like the ongoing operation will be known as part of the back-end state anyway, so you can actively cancel it right at the time the application initiates a new attempt, if it hasn’t been done by the application already.

Comment: How would I do this? Just hold a reference to the last given out Future and then cancel the old one when I give out a new one?

Comment: That could be a feasible approach. Since I don’t know anything about your back-end, I can’t tell whether there would be an alternative.